# MySQL: Increase table retrieval time with subqueries and links to other tables?

Tags: mysql, database

Following example: In my database I have two tables: One that stores user posts and their content and another that stores the likes of other users from these posts. If a user likes a post a new row gets inserted into the likes table.

If I make a SELECT call on the posts table it also returns the number of likes of the respective post using subqueries ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69c805/18)):

```
SELECT allPosts.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.postID = allPosts.id) AS likeCount
FROM posts allPosts
ORDER BY likeCount DESC
LIMIT 3;

| id | content | likeCount |
|----|---------|-----------|
|  2 |  Post 2 |         2 |
|  3 |  Post 3 |         1 |
|  1 |  Post 1 |         0 |
```

Problem: If, for example, you want to sort by `likeCount` using `ORDER BY`, likeCount must also be generated for each individual post at the same time, which is particularly problematic for very large tables with several thousands of posts. For example, it happened to me that a call took up to 10 seconds for a table containing about 2000 posts, which of course is too slow.

How can you solve this problem? How can I sort by likeCount without having to query likeCount for each individual post, but still sort the posts based on their number of likes?

I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlated subquery could be rewritten as `JOIN`:

```
SELECT allPosts.id, allPosts.content,
      COUNT(likes.postID) AS likeCount
FROM posts allPosts
LEFT JOIN likes
  ON likes.postID = allPosts.id
GROUP BY allPosts.id, allPosts.content
ORDER BY likeCount DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69c805/20/0)

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much!